# convert array from int8 to int in go

Tags: go

I have a problem to call function

```golang
sort.SearchInts(arrInt, 10)
```

because array (arrInt) has a type int8 and I need convert array to type int.
I guess I could go the long way and search an element in a for loop, but it sounds ugly and I guess there are better ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

An array is a contiguous sequence of items of the same size in memory:

```
Array of int8: [1 byte][1 byte][1 byte][1 byte][1 byte]...
```

If we need array of ints (tipically 8 bytes in amd64) we have:

```
Array of int: [8 bytes][8 bytes][8 bytes][8 bytes][8 bytes]...
```

There is no way to simply convert or cast from one type to the other, the only way to get the array of ints is creating a new array of int and converting all values from int8 to int.

On the other hand, if you only need to search in an array, doing all the conversion is overkill, the best approach is creating a function `SearchInt8`.

Here is where generics are useful, the same algorithm will be aplicable to types with the same operations but Golang lack of generics. To get this result, golang comes with the function `sort.Search` (https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Search) that accepts as second argument the function to implement the comparation for your type.

Reminder: to use Search functions, the array should be already sorted.

Answer (score 1):

`sort.SearchInts` is just a convenience wrapper of [`sort.Search`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Search) for slices of `int`s.

It's implemented like [this](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/af2ac479fc9e4833357a3281a67cd517d2da07ad/src/sort/search.go#L83):

```
func SearchInts(a []int, x int) int {
    return Search(len(a), func(i int) bool { return a[i] >= x })
}
```

So you can create a custom "`SearchInt8s`" function that does the same for `int8` arguments:

```
func SearchInt8s(a []int8, x int8) int {
    return sort.Search(len(a), func(i int) bool { return a[i] >= x })
}
```

Or (as another answer already said), just use [`sort.Search`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Search) directly:

```
sort.Search(len(arrInt), func(i int) bool { return arrInt[i] >= 10 })
```

Do note that the slice **must be sorted** before calling this, since this family of functions perform a binary search in a sorted slice.

Answer (score 0):

```
sort.Search(len(arrInt), func(i int) bool { return arrInt[i] >= 10 })
```